# Swift : How to center cell text

Tags: swift, uitableview, cell, text-alignment

I have a problem with my swift APP.

In my TableViewCell function i wrote

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath:indexPath) as MyCell
cell.setMyCell(self.data[0]["content"]!)
```

if i wrote

```
cell.textAlignment red line appear and say "textAlignment in unavailable: API deprecated"
```

Comment: presumably you have a label on your cell and you want to align the text in the label, not the whole cell...

Comment: Did you read the documentation on `textAligment` for `UITableViewCell`: "Deprecation Statement
Instead set the text alignment of the UILabel objects assigned to the textLabel and detailTextLabel properties." Apply the alignement to the wanted `UILabel`, not the cell.

Comment: N i didn't read. Thanks for your advise. I resolve it.

Comment: @AntonelloRossi: Often, when a method is deprecated, the doc says what new method to use if available. If not, there are often on SO questions about the issue.

Answer (score 14):

The correct answer for people using **Swift 4** would be:

```
cell.textLabel?.textAlignment = .center
```

Comment: how can i do is a have an image and a label in a cell, how can i center both?

Comment: You have to center your image first, then add contraints to your label after centered it in your image

Comment: The Answer above didn't work for me. Is there another way to solve the problem?

Comment: Have to try to set it in storyboard ?

Answer (score 4):

It will work only when your `UITableViewCell` Style is `default`

**Swift 4.1**

```
cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "DefaultCell")
cell.textLabel?.textAlignment = .center
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
 MyLabel1.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
```

Comment: `'textAlignment' is unavailable: APIs deprecated as of iOS 7 and earlier are unavailable in Swift`

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using a label on your cell?
Make sure the label is centered in the cell and give it a width that is big enough for your needs.
Then you can use two methods, you can align the label using the code:

```
label.textAlignment = .Center
```

or you can change this using the interface builder:

[image: Alignment example in interface builder]

Hope this helps!

Comment: `'textAlignment' is unavailable: APIs deprecated as of iOS 7 and earlier are unavailable in Swift`